# Are the rings $\mathbb{Z}_3[X] /(X^2 + 2)$ and $\mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$ isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

A friend and I are having a disagreement.

I think that $(x+1)(x-1) = 0 \in \mathbb{Z}_3[X] /(X^2 + 2)$ Which means that there are zero divisors in $\mathbb{Z}_3[X] /(X^2 + 2)$.  There is no equivalent in $\mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$.  Therefore they cannot be isomorphic.

However, I may be misunderstanding the elements of $\mathbb{Z}_3[X] /(X^2 + 2)$.

What are the elements of $\mathbb{Z}_3[X] /(X^2 + 2)$? Are there 9?  Are there zero divisors?

Comment: The elements can be written as $a+bX+(X^2+2), $ where $a,b\in\mathbb Z_3$ and $(X+1)(X-1)=X^2-1\equiv X^2+2$

Comment: Assuming by $\mathbb{Z}_3$ you mean the integers mod 3 (as opposed to the 3-adic integers) - then $\mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$ most certainly does have zero divisors such as $(0, 1)$ and $(1, 0)$.

Answer (score 2):

The two rings are indeed isomorphic.

As pointed out in the comments, $(X^2 -1) = (X+1)(X-1)$. We also have that the ideals $I = (X+1)$ and $J = (X-1)$ are comaximal. Indeed, since $(X+1)-(X-1) = 2$ is a unit, we have that $I + J = \mathbb{Z}_3[X]$. We can now conclude by the Chinese Remainder Theorem:
$$\mathbb{Z}_3[X]/(X^2 -1) \cong \mathbb{Z}_3[X]/(X+1) \times \mathbb{Z}_3[X]/(X-1) \cong \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$$

Explicitly, we can write the isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}_3[X]/(X^2 -1) \to \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$ as $X \mapsto (-1,1)$.

Comment: I don't think I quite understand your mapping here.  What does $x+1$ map to?  and similarly $x-1$?

Comment: Furthermore, what is $f(x+1) \cdot f(x-1)$?

Comment: @LascieL We have $x+1 \mapsto (0,2)$ and $x-1 \mapsto (-2,0)=(1,0)$. In general, an element of $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]/(x^2 -1)$ can always be written as $a + bx$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$, and that maps to $(a-b,a+b)$. We get this by extending $x \mapsto (-1,1)$ to all polynomials by enforcing the ring homomorphism axioms.

Comment: @LascieL In other words, if we call the mapping $\phi$, then we have $\phi(a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + \cdots) = a_0 + a_1 \phi(x) + a_2 \phi(x)^2 + \cdots$.